# Relation of row sums to largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory

I know that the largest eigenvalue of a graph is bounded between the minimal and maximal row sum of the matrix. If I have a $0-1$ symetric matrix (an adjacency matrix) and I know $k$ of the rows have at least $k$ zeros in them (more specifically, I know $k$ is the maximum size of an all zeros principal sub-matrix of the adjacency matrix), is there anything else I can tell about the largest eigenvalue (or others eigenvalues)?

Is there anything I can tell about the eigenvalues which implies I have that kind of principal sub-matrix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for relationships between the maximum independent set and the eigenvalues.  If you search with those terms you will find several.  For example, [Haemers proved](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82168366.pdf) that the maximum size of an independent set is bounded above by $$ n\frac{-\lambda_1\lambda_n}{\delta^2-\lambda_1\lambda_n},$$ where $\lambda_1,\lambda_n$ are the largest and smallest eigenvalues and $\delta$ is the minimum degree.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know the name of the article?